# How do I prevent the cart modal (ajax) from opening after adding a product?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, shopify

Every time I add a new product, the cart opens up as a modal. I do need, want and like the modal method of the cart, I just want to disable it from opening every time a product gets added.

The code has to be somewhere in here: [http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0656/8697/t/7/assets/ajaxify.js?8066](http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0656/8697/t/7/assets/ajaxify.js?806).

I've tried removing `buildCart(cart)` (line 711 in ajaxify.js) from this method:

```
cartUpdateCallback = function (cart) {
    // Update quantity and price
    updateCountPrice(cart);

    switch (settings.method) {
      case 'flip':
        $('.flip-cart span').html(cart.item_count);
        break;
      case 'modal':
        buildCart(cart); // <<<
        break;
      case 'drawer':
        buildCart(cart);
        if ( !$drawerContainer.hasClass('is-visible') ) {
          showDrawer();
        } else {
          scrollTop();
        }
        break;
    }
  };
```

This does prevent the cart modal from opening after a product is added, but also disables me from opening the cart if I click on the cart button.

What could I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It never really occurred to me that would be desired functionality, but I totally understand. Follow these steps to get the modal cart working as you'd like:

Note: My line numbers may be off compared to your version as I'm looking at the latest version that will be merged into [Timber master](https://github.com/Shopify/Timber) soon.

1. Add `cartToggleCallback` after `cartUpdateCallback` under the Private function variable declarations. This is around line 260.
2. In `showModal`, change `Shopify.getCart(cartUpdateCallback);` to `Shopify.getCart(cartToggleCallback);` This is around line 475.
3. Make a complete copy of `cartUpdateCallback` and name the new function `cartToggleCallback`. This is around line 689.
4. Comment out `buildCart(cart);` from `case 'modal` in `cartUpdateCallback`

The steps above will create separate callbacks for when a product is added vs when the cart is toggled opened. Let me know if you have any issues!

Edit: To fix the issue in the comment below,  replace the `showModal` function with the following:

```
showModal = function (toggle) {
  $body.addClass('ajaxcart--is-visible');
  Shopify.getCart(cartUpdateCallback);
};
```

Comment: There's a new, small, issue:

When the cart is empty,
And I app one new product,
The cart count and cart get updated (so when I open the cart modal, I see the added product in the list).

But when I add a second product,
The cart count (top right corner) get's updated,
But when I open the cart modal, the second product is not in the list. It looks like the cart modal stops updating the products added after it's opened and closed manually.

Take a look: http://goo.gl/nx2hh.

How could I solve this?

Comment: Updated the answer to include a fix for that.