# How can I update the text dynamically without refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, ajax, shopify

I am using Shopify template. Under Ajaxify.js.liquid, I had been modified the codes according to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26412955/how-do-i-prevent-the-cart-modal-ajax-from-opening-after-adding-a-product/26426214#26426214) from prevent the cart modal ajax from opening after adding a product.

Currently I want to build something like [redmart](https://redmart.com/fresh-produce). When you hit add cart, it will show the number of item selected. I can get call the amount of item when I hit add cart, but need to refresh the page in order to work. I tried to modify Ajaxify.js.liquid but no luck that I couldn't find specific variant_id for each item when I hit the add cart button.

Once again, I want to build something like [redmart](https://redmart.com/fresh-produce) that the cart button will show number of item that had been added to cart.

In product collection page, each product has "add to cart" button below. Above that button, I had added item quantity for each product.

**Product-grid-item.liquid (Add cart button)**

```
<form action="/cart/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="addToCartForm">
        <select name="id" id="productSelect" class="product-variants">
          {% for variant in product.variants %}
            {% if variant.available %}

              <option {% if variant == product.selected_or_first_available_variant %} selected="selected" {% endif %} data-sku="{{ variant.sku }}" value="{{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.title }} - {{ variant.price | money_with_currency }}</option>

            {% else %}
              <option disabled="disabled">
                {{ variant.title }} - {{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}
              </option>
            {% endif %}
          {% endfor %}
        </select>

 {% for variant in product.variants %}
    {% if variant.available %}

        Variant id: {{ variant.id }}

        {% for item in cart.items %}
          {% if item.variant_id == variant.id %}
                Item amount: <span id="item-cart-quantity">{{ item.quantity }}</span>
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}  

        {% if settings.product_quantity_enable %}
          <label for="quantity" class="quantity-selector">{{ 'products.product.quantity' | t }}</label>
          <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" class="quantity-selector">
        {% endif %}

        <button type="submit" name="add" id="addToCart" class="btn">
          <span class="icon icon-cart"></span>
          <span id="addToCartText">{{ 'products.product.add_to_cart' | t }}</span>
        </button>
        {% if settings.product_quantity_message %}
          <span id="variantQuantity" class="variant-quantity"></span>
        {% endif %}
</form>
```

I want to update "#item-cart-quantity" dynamically, but I am having problem in Ajaxify.js.liquid which I could not get item's variant id from the specific item I added to.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: @Bruno question updated.